# No distributions at all found for some package

Tags: python, django

**error when installing some package but its actualy existing example django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5**

> Downloading/unpacking django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5 (from -r
>   requirements.example.pip (line 13))   **Could not find any downloads
>   that satisfy the requirement**  django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5(from
>   -r requirements.example.pip (line 13))
>   **No distributions at all found** for django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5  Storing debug log for failure in /home/pd/.pip/pip.log
>   (peecs)pd@admin:~/proj/django/peecs$ pip install
>   django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5 --allow-unverified
>   django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5 Downloading/unpacking
>   django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5   Could not find any downloads that
>   satisfy the requirement django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5   Some
>   externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external
>   django-ajax-filtered-fields to allow). Cleaning up... No distributions
>   at all found for django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5 Storing debug log
>   for failure in /home/pd/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Could someone please edit this "error when installing some package but its actualy existing example" into a clear sentence? I'd have a go but my situation simply concerns Django and not django-ajax-filtered... so i don't want to mess up the meaning if it is different from my situation.

Comment: you can try to input below: date check whether the time is c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution ,Try with **--allow-unverified**

> syntax: **pip install packagename=version  --allow-unverified  packagename**

Some package condains insecure and unverifiable files. it will not download to the system . and it can be solved by using this method **--allow-unverified**. it will allow the installation.

> **Eg:** pip install django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5 --allow-unverified
>   django-ajax-filtered-fields

Comment: Not sure if my situation is the same or not. I just wish to install Django but get the same error message.  I try `pip install Django --allow-unverified Django` but still get msg `No distributions at all found for Django`

Comment: can you post error message in "gist" and comment the link.

Comment: I don't know what "gist" is, but try this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PXEzq3xHRV7yjZ-8xcGko3SU_T73dewZM9tImNqC0iI/edit?usp=sharing  BTW: it may have to do with company (Intel) security.

Comment: @MartinF A gist is a github code snippet; a service like pastebin. When I was at Intel I had no trouble installing python packages.

Comment: @Hack-R Many of the users are facing the issues, I think you already configured all required package in your PC that is why you are not faced this issue.

Answer (score 15):

Note that this error may also occure because you are using too old version of pip. Then it can be solved by:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

You can check your version by:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: `# pip install --upgrade pip
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log`

Answer (score 3):

**Proxy Settings**

Still unsure if *my* issue has the same cause as with the OP, but one error message was the same:

```
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django
No distributions at all found for Django
```

Talking to a colleague exposed it was a site-security-based issue.
The following commands were required:

```
set https_proxy=*https proxy*
set http_proxy=*http proxy*
pip install Django
```

where `*https proxy*` and `*http proxy*` are appropriate URLs-with-ports for our site.

```
Downloading/unpacking Django
Installing collected packages: Django
Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: In my case I had overlook setting up https_proxy. I though http_proxy and no_proxy were enough. Sure thing when I set up the proxy i just needed pip install Django

Answer (score 3):

The only solution worked for me:

1. uninstall pip (pip uninstall pip)
2. download pip package from pypi (https://pypi.org/project/pip/)
3. execute python setup.py install  (not using easy_install)
4. then you can install any package you want.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the logs reveals the following line:

```
less .pip/pip.log

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/WSGIUtils/: connection error: [Errno1] _ssl.c:493: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

In an earlier version of the comment I attributed this behaviour to https://pypi.python.org, but this is not the issue, since I can contact this site (from another computer!) with firefox and all certificates are OK. So this is probably a problem of some installations of pip---I encounter it unter SLES 11 which has (among other things) the "oldstable" openssl-0.9.8.

Comment: Is this an *answer* or a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading pip. 
Version 7.1.2 does not have this issue.

```
easy_install pip==7.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I did following to install Openpyxl in Python version 3.5 after the following error with command

**pip install openpyxl --allow-unverified openpyxl**

```
DEPRECATION: --allow-unverified has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
Collecting openpyxl
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000044AF080>, 'Connection to pypi
.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/openpyxl/
Operation cancelled by user
```

**C:\Softwares\Python\Scripts>set https_proxy=*My proxy***

**C:\Softwares\Python\Scripts>pip install openpyxl --allow-unverified openpyxl**

```
DEPRECATION: --allow-unverified has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
Collecting openpyxl
  Downloading openpyxl-2.4.8.tar.gz (156kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 3.7MB/s
Collecting jdcal (from openpyxl)
  Downloading jdcal-1.3.tar.gz
Collecting et_xmlfile (from openpyxl)
  Downloading et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: jdcal, et-xmlfile, openpyxl
  Running setup.py install for jdcal ... done
  Running setup.py install for et-xmlfile ... done
  Running setup.py install for openpyxl ... done
Successfully installed et-xmlfile-1.0.1 jdcal-1.3 openpyxl-2.4.8
```

That worked!    Thanks Martin F for your tip.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of solutions to this, most effectively coming down to **update PIP**.
On MacOS (Sierra), This was my solution:

- [Download python3 installer of choice](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)
- Install Package (this includes a newer version of pip)
- Remove old version of python from `$PATH` in `~/.bash_login` (new one added by installer)
- `pip3 install packagename` (no sudo)

After that I was still prompted to update pip and did so: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1):

You can install the library manually:

git clone https://github.com/roddds/django-ajax-filtered-fields.git

then go to the folder:

pip install .