# Upgrade pip without upgrading python on centos 6.2

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, centos6

I have a server which is running centos 6.2 and a python(2.6.66) app running on it. I cannot upgrade os and python. I want to upgrade request on the system to 2.19.1. When I try to run the command it gives me an error:

```
pip install requests==2.19.1
Downloading/unpacking requests==2.19.1
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement requests==2.19.1
No distributions at all found for requests==2.19.1
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

My current pip version is:

```
pip --version 1.0.2
```

Any suggestions? thanks!

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019222/9335996

based on this answer in order to update requests, I need to update pip.

but found a way to do it without upgrading pip. Manually install request.

---

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

gives same error as shown above for the requests.

Comment: what your command is doing is actually installing a library called `requests`, can you confirm if you want to update `pip` or `requests`?

Answer (score 1):

Had to do it manually:

Download it on server:
https://github.com/requests/requests

using: curl -OL https://github.com/requests/requests/tarball/master

Then install using: pip install .

I got additional requirements for chardet>=3.0.2,<3.1.0 ; idna>=2.5,<2.8 ; urllib3>=1.21.1,<1.24 which I had to install manually.

finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you want to upgrade requests (2.19.1) is the latest version, so just do

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Download `get-pip.py` from [the official site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)  and run this code:

```
$ python get-pip.py
```